# Execute transforms inside BizTalk inbound pipeline?

Tags: biztalk

I have messages arriving which need to be transformed, but after the transform I need to promote certain properties to the message context. Is this possible to do in the receive pipleline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a link which pretty much describes exactly what I want to do:

http://www.richardhallgren.com/transform-and-split-messages-using-an-xslt-transformation-pipeline-component-and-the-xmldissasembler/

I will try this out and post back with results.